# Platform to Simulate FLO of Majorana

Tags: simulation, surface-code, majorana-particle, linear-optics

Is there any python (other languages are also OK) library/platform/toolbox, open-source, to simulate Majorana in FLO (Fermion Linear Optics) as done in [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.13055). I tried to look for the platform that was used in the article and did not find it.

Comment: What *did* they use in the article?

Comment: They did not dive into details, just said it is FLO